# wxpython: adding rows to wxgrid dynamically does not fit to panel

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wxgrid inside a resizable scrollable panel. I dynamically add/hide/show rows in wxgrid. When I try to add/show more rows in wxgrid, it does not fit to the available space in panel but instead occupies a small area it had been occupying previously with a scrollbar for wxgrid.

Like this:

[image]

But after I resize the panel or frame, then it fits perfectly. Like this:

[image]

How can I make it to fit properly without needing to resize the panel?

I have tried all combinations of wx.EXPAND, wx.GROW, wx.ALL while adding grid to sizer and also tried gridobj.Layout() Nothing works. Any Ideas?

Iam using wx 3.0 with python 2.7 on windows 7

Edit:
Here's my code

controls.py

```
import wx
import wx.grid
import wx.combo
class SimpleGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.CreateGrid(10, 5)
        for i in range(10):
            self.SetRowLabelValue(i,str(i))

class ListCtrlComboPopup(wx.ListCtrl, wx.combo.ComboPopup):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.gfobj = parent
        self.PostCreate(wx.PreListCtrl())
        self.parent = parent
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.__init__(self)

    def AddItem(self, txt):
        self.InsertStringItem(self.GetItemCount(), txt)
        self.Select(0)

    def GetSelectedItems(self):
      del self.gfobj.selection[:]
      current = -1
      while True:
            next = self.GetNextSelected(current)
            if next == -1:
                return
            self.gfobj.selection.append(next)
            current = next

    def onItemSelected(self, event):
        item = event.GetItem()
        self.GetSelectedItems()
        self.parent.draw_plot()

    def onItemDeSelected(self, event):
        self.GetSelectedItems()
        self.parent.draw_plot()


    def Init(self):
        """ This is called immediately after construction finishes.  You can
        use self.GetCombo if needed to get to the ComboCtrl instance. """
        self.value = -1
        self.curitem = -1


    def Create(self, parent):
        """ Create the popup child control. Return True for success. """
        wx.ListCtrl.Create(self, parent,
                           style=wx.LC_LIST|wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.onItemSelected)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED, self.onItemDeSelected)
        return True


    def GetControl(self):
        """ Return the widget that is to be used for the popup. """
        return self

    def SetStringValue(self, val):
        """ Called just prior to displaying the popup, you can use it to
        'select' the current item. """
        idx = self.FindItem(-1, val)
        if idx != wx.NOT_FOUND:
            self.Select(idx)


    def GetStringValue(self):
        """ Return a string representation of the current item. """
        a = self.GetItemText(self.value)
        if self.value >= 0:
            return a
        return ""

    def OnPopup(self):
        """ Called immediately after the popup is shown. """
        self.state = []
        for i in range(self.GetItemCount()):
            item = self.GetItem(itemId=i)
            self.state.append(item.GetState())
            #print self.state
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.OnPopup(self)

    def OnDismiss(self):
        " Called when popup is dismissed. """
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.OnDismiss(self)
```

main.py

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
from controls import SimpleGrid
from controls import ListCtrlComboPopup


class GraphFrame(wx.Frame):
    title = 'Demo: Data Trending Tool'

    def __init__(self):
        self.selection = []
        self.displaySize = wx.DisplaySize() 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title,
                 style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                 size = (self.displaySize[0]/2, self.displaySize[1]/2))        
        self.containingpanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.toppanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.splittedwin = wx.SplitterWindow(self.containingpanel, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.SP_3D | wx.SP_BORDER)
        self.splittedwin.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)
        self.gridpanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.splittedwin,-1, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)        
        self.panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.splittedwin,-1, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        #### GRID
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self.gridpanel)
        self.gridpanelsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.gridpanelsizer.Add(self.grid, wx.GROW)
        self.gridpanel.SetSizer(self.gridpanelsizer)
        self.gridpanelsizer.Fit(self)             
        #### COMBOBOX
        self.cc = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(self.toppanel, style=wx.CB_READONLY, size=(200,-1), )
        self.cc.SetPopupMaxHeight(140)
        popup = ListCtrlComboPopup(self)
        self.cc.SetPopupControl(popup)
        self.cc.SetText("--select--")
        # Add some items to the listctrl
        for i in range(10):
            popup.AddItem(str(i))

        #### SIZER FOR COMBOBOX 
        self.cbpanelsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.cbpanelsizer.Add(self.cc, border = 5,flag = wx.LEFT)
        self.toppanel.SetSizer(self.cbpanelsizer)


        self.splittedwin.SplitHorizontally(self.gridpanel,self.panel,100)

        ##### SIZER FOR CONTAININGPANEL
        self.cpsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.cpsizer.Add(self.splittedwin, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.containingpanel.SetSizer(self.cpsizer)
        self.cpsizer.Fit(self.containingpanel)

        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainsizer.Add(self.toppanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainsizer.Add(self.containingpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainsizer)

        self.panel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.gridpanel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.gridpanel.SetupScrolling()
        self.draw_plot()

    def draw_plot(self):
        for i in range(10):  
          if i in self.selection:
             self.grid.ShowRow(i)
          else:
             self.grid.HideRow(i) 
        self.Layout()
        #self.gridpanel.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":

  app = wx.PySimpleApp()
  app.frame = GraphFrame()
  app.frame.Show()

  app.MainLoop()
```

To simulate:
1. run main.py It displays a splitted window with a grid with single row in one panel.

2. Use the drop down to select more than one item (hold ctrl and select)
3. The wxgrid is cramped to one row space with a wxgrid scrollbar
4. Resize the panel using the splitter or resize the window. Now all the selected rows appear as required.

Comment: Did you try using self.Fit() on the window after adding new data/rows?

Comment: yes, but that didnt work either

Comment: @Lokla or maybe am missing something. I have edited my question to include a simplified code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out!!!

With the help of [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235833/wxpython-hide-and-show-panel), found that the problem was trying to redraw the `gridpanel` using `gridpanel.Layout()`. Instead redrawing the `gridpanelsizer` using `gridpanelsizer.Layout()` worked out!!

Updated `main.py`:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
from controls import SimpleGrid
from controls import ListCtrlComboPopup


class GraphFrame(wx.Frame):
    title = 'Demo: Data Trending Tool'

    def __init__(self):
        self.selection = []
        self.displaySize = wx.DisplaySize() 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title,
                 style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                 size = (self.displaySize[0]/2, self.displaySize[1]/2))        
        self.containingpanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.toppanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.splittedwin = wx.SplitterWindow(self.containingpanel, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.SP_3D | wx.SP_BORDER)
        self.splittedwin.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)
        self.gridpanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.splittedwin,-1, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)        
        self.panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.splittedwin,-1, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        #### GRID
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self.gridpanel)
        self.gridpanelsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.gridpanelsizer.Add(self.grid, wx.GROW)
        self.gridpanel.SetSizer(self.gridpanelsizer)
        self.gridpanelsizer.Fit(self)             
        #### COMBOBOX
        self.cc = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(self.toppanel, style=wx.CB_READONLY, size=(200,-1), )
        self.cc.SetPopupMaxHeight(140)
        popup = ListCtrlComboPopup(self)
        self.cc.SetPopupControl(popup)
        self.cc.SetText("--select--")
        # Add some items to the listctrl
        for i in range(10):
            popup.AddItem(str(i))

        #### SIZER FOR COMBOBOX 
        self.cbpanelsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.cbpanelsizer.Add(self.cc, border = 5,flag = wx.LEFT)
        self.toppanel.SetSizer(self.cbpanelsizer)


        self.splittedwin.SplitHorizontally(self.gridpanel,self.panel,100)

        ##### SIZER FOR CONTAININGPANEL
        self.cpsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.cpsizer.Add(self.splittedwin, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.containingpanel.SetSizer(self.cpsizer)
        self.cpsizer.Fit(self.containingpanel)

        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainsizer.Add(self.toppanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainsizer.Add(self.containingpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainsizer)

        self.panel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.gridpanel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.gridpanel.SetupScrolling()
        self.draw_plot()

    def draw_plot(self):
        for i in range(10):  
          if i in self.selection:
             self.grid.ShowRow(i)
          else:
             self.grid.HideRow(i) 
        #self.Layout()
        self.gridpanelsizer.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":

  app = wx.PySimpleApp()
  app.frame = GraphFrame()
  app.frame.Show()

  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

A great tool to debug this is the WIT (http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool)

With your corrected code I can get it to grow by forcing the sash position, not ideal, but it shows that the 'problem' is with the splitter.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
from controls import SimpleGrid
from controls import ListCtrlComboPopup


class GraphFrame(wx.Frame):
    title = 'Demo: Data Trending Tool'

    def __init__(self):
        self.selection = []
        self.displaySize = wx.DisplaySize() 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title,
                          style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                          size = (self.displaySize[0]/2, self.displaySize[1]/2))        
        self.containingpanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.toppanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.splittedwin = wx.SplitterWindow(self.containingpanel, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.SP_3D | wx.SP_BORDER)
        self.splittedwin.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)
        self.gridpanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.splittedwin,-1, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)        
        self.panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.splittedwin,-1, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        #### GRID
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self.gridpanel)
        self.gridpanelsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.gridpanelsizer.Add(self.grid, wx.GROW)
        self.gridpanel.SetSizer(self.gridpanelsizer)
        self.gridpanelsizer.Fit(self)             
        #### COMBOBOX
        self.cc = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(self.toppanel, style=wx.CB_READONLY, size=(200,-1), )
        self.cc.SetPopupMaxHeight(140)
        popup = ListCtrlComboPopup(self)
        self.cc.SetPopupControl(popup)
        self.cc.SetText("--select--")
        # Add some items to the listctrl
        for i in range(10):
            popup.AddItem(str(i))

        #### SIZER FOR COMBOBOX 
        self.cbpanelsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.cbpanelsizer.Add(self.cc, border = 5,flag = wx.LEFT)
        self.toppanel.SetSizer(self.cbpanelsizer)


        self.splittedwin.SplitHorizontally(self.gridpanel, self.panel, 50)

        ##### SIZER FOR CONTAININGPANEL
        self.cpsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.cpsizer.Add(self.splittedwin, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.containingpanel.SetSizer(self.cpsizer)

        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainsizer.Add(self.toppanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainsizer.Add(self.containingpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainsizer)

        self.panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.gridpanel.SetupScrolling()
        self.draw_plot()

    def draw_plot(self):
        for i in range(10):  
            if i in self.selection:
                self.grid.ShowRow(i)
            else:
                self.grid.HideRow(i)

        s = self.grid.GetBestSize()
        print(s)
        self.splittedwin.SetSashPosition(s[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectableApp
    app = InspectableApp()
    app.frame = GraphFrame()
    app.frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: sorry, I have corrected the exception in my code. correcting it to flag=wx.GROW, the problem still persists.

Comment: Thank you Werner. The actual problem turned out to be redrawing the sizer for grid. However, your solution provides a neater UI when compared. Am going to include that in my code :):)